# How do I make TailwindCSS Group-hover work in codesandbox?

Tags: tailwind-css

I grabbed markup from - https://tailwindcomponents.com/component/button-dropdown

And tried to apply the same markup using a Codesandbox instance.

I updated the module for visibility in tailwind.js adding the group-hover variant. Hovering over the button does not show the element targeted by group-hover.

What am I missing?

https://codesandbox.io/s/2p9jj3wknr

Answer (score 0):

This error was because the CDN is loading a standard version of the library. No updates in tailwind.js are being used in my instance of Codesandbox.